# If $S$ is a set consisting of $n$ IID random variables, what is the probability there are $k$ elements smaller than a random element of $S$?

Tags: probability, order-statistics

I think my answer to the following question is nonsense, and I would like to know what I did wrong/a hint in the correct direction. Suppose that $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are sampled IID at random from a distribution with CDF $\Phi$. Let $S = \{ X_1,\dots, X_n\}$. Pick $X\in S$ uniformly at random, and let $K$ be the number of elements smaller than $X$. What is $P(K=k)$?

Here is my attempt. Given $X$, we have $$P(K=k| X) = \binom{n-1}{k}\Phi(X)^k(1-\Phi(X))^{n-1-k}.$$
In particular, assuming $\Phi$ is absolutely continuous, the law of the unconscious statistician yields
$$P(K=k) = \binom{n-1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x)^k(1-\Phi(x))^{n-1-k}\Phi'(x)\,dx = \binom{n-1}{k}\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-1-k}\,dx = 1,$$
since the last integral is $B(k+1,n-k)$, where $B$ is the Beta function.

Of course, this calculation is nonsense. So my question is, where did I go wrong, and what is a ***hint*** in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you found 1 in your last equality. With $$B(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{ab}\frac{1}{\binom{a+b}{a}}$$
you find
$\mathbb P(K=k)=\frac{1}{n}$, which is very logical given the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: My thoughts were $$\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-1-k}\,dx = \frac{k!(n-k-1)!}{(n-1)!} = \frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{k}},$$ by definition of the Beta function. But I agree, the value of $P(K=k) = n^{-1}$ seems a far more logical answer.

Comment: But as you mentioned, that integral should equal $B(k+1, n-k)$ and as @Will points out $$B(k+1, n-k) = \frac{n+1}{(k+1)(n-k)\binom{n+1}{k+1}}=\frac{1}{(n-k)\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{1}{n\binom{n-1}{k}}$$. So you either evaluated the integral incorrectly, or simplified the Beta function incorrectly.

Comment: @BBBBBB there is a flaw in your integral calculation. For instance for $n=k+1$ the left-hand side is $1/(k+1)$ whereas the right-hand side is $1$.